# BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash in SessionsController#create Rails 'invalid hash'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, session, bcrypt

**Error**
BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash in SessionsController#create
invalid hash

Request
Parameters:

{"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "email"=>[""], "session_password"=>"[FILTERED]", "commit"=>"Log in"}

**Code**

1. Session Controller

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:password]) #error line 

      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to 'posts/index'
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = 'Invalid email or password'
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to '/login'
  end
end
```

2. User Controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authorized, only: [:show]
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def index
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    @user.password = params[:password]
    if @user.save
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private
  def user_params
    params.
      permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end


end
```

Form

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "signup.css" %>

<%= form_with(model: user) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_field :name,placeholder:"Full Name", class: 'signup-textfield'%>
  </div>
  <div class="field">

    <%= f.email_field :email, placeholder: "Email", class: 'signup-textfield' %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.password_field :password,placeholder:'Password', class: 'signup-textfield' %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation,placeholder: 'Confirm password', class: 'signup-textfield' %>
  </div>
  <div class = "field">

    <p>Investor</p>
    <%= f.radio_button :type, 'Investor',class:'radiobutton' %>
    <p>Investee</p>
    <%= f.radio_button :type, 'Investee', class:'radiobutton'%>

  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit id: "signup-button" %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

When I create a user in the rails console, it outputs a hash. I don't know why it states invalid hash. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Your params do not contain the key `password` - it does however contain the key `session_password`. Bcrypt is complaining since you're doing `user.authenticate(nil)` - nil is of course not a valid hash. The most likely culprit here is the form.

Comment: @max I just added the form to my post. What do you suggest changing instead?

Comment: That looks like its the wrong form. You should have a separate sign in form. On a side note do not use placeholders instead of labels. Its a huge failure in terms of useability and accessibility and pet peive of mine. https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/06/placeholder-attribute/